# "sort" from algorithm module gives ambiguous/no type error

Tags: sorting, nim-lang

Running Nim 0.17.0, tested on Windows 8.1 running with the vcc 2017 toolchain, the following produces an error during compiling:

```
import algorithm

var toSort = @["b", "c", "d"]
for sorted in toSort.sort(system.cmp):
  echo sorted
```

I'm very new to Nim, but what is the issue with my `sort` call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `sort` procedure doesn't return anything. It modifies the list in-place. You want to use `sorted` instead:

```
import algorithm

var toSort = @["b", "c", "d"]
for sorted in toSort.sorted(system.cmp):
  echo sorted
```

Comment: Rereading the code examples from the [sort documentation](https://nim-lang.org/docs/algorithm.html#sort,openArray[T],proc(T,T)) make this clear to me now.  Thank you!